# How can I pass a function that use lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'v trid this, but it doesn't work

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int(*func)(int,int);

void test(func fun, int k, int b)
{
    int result = fun(k, b);
    cout << "result: " << result;
}

int main()
{
    test([](int k, int b){ return k*2 + b},2,3);
}
```

what should I do to let it work?

**This question has resolved:**

This problem is can not convert 'anonymous-namespace':: to 'func', follow Joachim' advice, use the `std::function` can fix it.

This is the fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int test(std::function<int (int,int)> fun, int k, int b)
{
    return fun(k, b);
}

int main()
{
    int result = test(
        [](int k, int b)
        { 
            return k*2 + b;
        },2,3);
    cout << "result: " << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How* doesn't it work? Do you get compiler errors? What errors then? Please **edit your question** you include the *complete* and *unedited* error messages. You may want to read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Your code worked for me, once i added a ';' after return k*2 + b in ideone

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: @KubaOber, how lame is that? The syntax of a language is not a trivial matter. Voting to reopen; besides there are additional issues as is evident in the answers below.

Comment: @Johan: Basically by not closing such questions you're going against the established goals of SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions

Comment: @Johan: Think of the applicability of this question: who does it help. Does someone else having made a typo like this benefit from this question or its answers? Does it help *anyone but the asker at all*. The answer is no. Thus it's off-topic here. There's lots of questions that do help one person out there, even very good ones, but they still don't belong.

Comment: @Johan: It has nothing to do with the quality of the question! Just its *scope*.

Comment: Did you notice "besides there are other issues"... If it was a question about a naked typo I'd see your point but it's not. And look at the answers. See this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/19242058/650492 I did not know that, that's good info. So no I disagree on this question.

Comment: I never learned c++ yet so that I ask this question this way. thanks all of your words, I'll change better next time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function):

```
using func_t = std::function<int(int, int)>;

void test(func_t fun, int k, int b)
{
    ...
}
```

Or just templates:

```
template<typename F>
void test(F fun, int k, int b)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a syntax error:

```
 test([](int k, int b){ return k*2 + b },2,3);
                                   //^ here you missed semicolon!
```

The above code misses a semicolon as indicated in the comment.

And here it is corrected:

```
 test([](int k, int b){ return k*2 + b; },2,3);
                                   // ^ corrected!
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should enable the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard in your compiler. with GCC 4.8, compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g`.

Then you should declare

```
void test(std::function<int(int,int)>fun, int k, int b)
```

A [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) (i.e. `std::function`) returned by a lambda construct is *not* a pointer to function (since it mixes code and closed data).

At last, don't forget the semicolon in the lambda's return as others answered

```
 test([](int k, int b){ return k*2 + b;},2,3);
```

Comment: A lambda is definitely NOT a `std::function`. The type of a lambda is unique and can't be written out. I.e. `auto x = []{}; auto y = []{}` defines two different types; they can't both have type `std::function<void(void)>`. Additionally, a stateless lambda such as these **can** be converted to a function pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Left out a semi-colon for the return statement in the lambda.

```
int main()
{
    test([](int k, int b){ return k*2 + b;},2,3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use function pointer, but std::function type in your test function instead:

```
typedef std::function<void (int, int)> func;

void test(func fun, int k, int b) {/*Same as before*/}
```

Comment: Why? Neither is really efficient. Just pass it by `T const&` instead. But all three options are allowed.